# Can Mathematica be set to remind user to save after a set number of unsaved edits have occurred or after a set amount of time has passed?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, system, user-interface

I lost half a night's work just now because after about 6 months of learning and working with Mathematica it finally decided to crash on me for the very first time. Yeah my bad. At least I can remember what I did. Still I am now determined to find some way to not let this happen again. I couldn't find a setting for it in Preferences but I suspect there may be system options I can place at the top of a notebook. Please help.

Comment: Look up `NotebookAutoSave` in the documentation. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookAutoSave.html

Comment: Welcome to the pro level. I crash _Mathematica_ at least twice a day! ;)

Comment: @flinty thanks for the tip but it only gave what i thought was a useless use case: how to create notebooks that automatically save. there is no information on how to set existing notebooks to autosave.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher lol i am far from pro but i am making great strides every day.

Comment: @JulesManson You could do CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave] = True

Comment: Or, even better, do not program in Notebooks. Use an IDE ...

Comment: @RolfMertig if you mean Eclipse it's too confusing for novices like me. It feels over engineered. Not sure how to install the mathematica package and Eclipse is designed with so many features that the fundamentals to get up and running get lost in the complexity that results in a steep learning curve. Other than a convenient Autosave feature what are other pros (and cons) of using Eclipse or another IDE?

Comment: @RolfMertig thanks for yours suggestion. I'll try that. But how could I set `CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], NotebookAutoSave] = True` to only do an Autosave after say about 10 edits or after 30 minutes?

Comment: Although you can create your own dynamic event monitor for edits, I think a habbit of checking the "*" flag on the window title periodicly may benifit more.